# Same SSH login process works for user A but not for user B

Tags: ssh-keys

I created an SSH public key for my root user. I copied it to /root/.ssh/authorized_keys, and saved.

The key is only `ssh-rsa key`. (It's one row, `ssh-rsaSPACEkey`, no further spaces or brakes).

1. `/.ssh` is 700.
2. `/.ssh/authrozied_keys` is 600.
3. owner and group are same as the USERNAME.

I can log in SSH just fine with root and I repeated the same algorithm for creating, pasting and loading the key, for my primary user under `/home/USERNAME` **but I can't login with it** - It says "No supported authentication methods available".

### Notes:

1. I did load private keys for both of these users.
2. Both keys are ssh-2 rsa.
3. Both keys include 4096 bytes.
4. I use Putty to login, and load the private keys with pageant.
5. Did `service ssh restart` before trying.

### Update 1 - Relevant public key:

Here's he public key I'm having problems with (copied as is from /home/USERNAME/.ssh/authrorized_keys):

```
ssh-rsa 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
```

### Update 2 - Seemingly-relevant sshd_config directives

I put an image as for some reason I can't paste syntax I cut or copy from Putty:

[image]

Comment: What are directory permissions all the way up to `/`?

Comment: I think I didn't understand you.

Comment: Look at `/var/log/auth` - most problems have detailed description here.

Comment: the permissions are correct 600, but who is the USER, if that is still root it should be chown 'ed to the user whos home directory is being used

Comment: It's not root (I can log in with root fine), I meant to write USERNAME to not expose the nick as a security-principle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems with public keys are almost always permissions related.

Check the ownership of the authorized_keys file in your non-root user's home directory. You mention mode octals of 0700 and 0600 for the directory and file respectively. However, you don't mention ownership.

Be sure the owner **is not** root, for the `authorized_keys` file, as well as as for `/home/USERNAME/.ssh/`. Also, the authorized_keys file is public information. It's typical to give this file read access to all, via octals 0644. However, your permissions should work in this case provided your file ownership is correct.

To clear this up in case of confusion, posting the output of `# ls -la /home/<USERNAME>/.ssh/` would abolish any doubt as to the permissions.

Comment: Did chown (and chgrp) both to USERNAME. in ll it's -rw------- 1 USERNAME USERNAME  721 Oct 26 10:18 authorized_keys (I also restarted SSH service because I didn't know if it's a must) YET, I still get the same error message from above.

Comment: I'm assuming with no supported authentication methods as an error message, you're probably trying to disable password based authentication? Editing your post to contain your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file from your servers would help in identifying why this happens. It could be that you've disabled password authentication and not enabled private key authentication (it may be commented, as is common).

Comment: Yes I changed PasswordAuthentication (in the end of file) from yes to no, without touching the commented instance of this directive. I didn't enable private key authentication --- I thought it's already enabled given the face I log in with a private key as root without any problem.

Comment: Most default sshd configurations specify that root may only log in via private key, or `without-password`. This *implies* that key based login is enabled, but only applies to root. This behavior overrides the `pubkeyauthentication` and `rsaauthentication` directives.

Comment: I hear of this behavior for the first time. I have uploaded an image with the seemingly-relevant piece of directives from sshd_config... I didn't understand what to change there (if there is anything relevant in that file, to allow non-root users to login with private keys and without passwords as well).

Comment: @SmallLoadOf1M --- The problem was that the dir /home/USERNAME/.ssh itself didn't have owner and group as USERNAME has. The problem is now solved.